# Detectar cada pulsación de tecla en una caja de texto

Tags: angular

Cómo puedo detectar cada pulsación de tecla en una caja de texto de búsqueda?. De forma que a cada letra o caracter que escribo ejecuto una función llamada "buscarHeroe3(buscarTexto.value)"

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" (submit)="false" (keyup.enter)="buscarHeroe3(buscarTexto.value)">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Buscar héroe"  #buscarTexto (change)="buscarHeroe3(buscarTexto.value)">
  <button (click)="buscarHeroe3(buscarTexto.value)"
      class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">Buscar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Cambia el nombre del atributo `change` por `keydown`

Answer (score 0):

Reemplaza el evento **(change)** por **(keyup)**

```
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Buscar héroe"  #buscarTexto (keyup)="buscarHeroe3(buscarTexto.value)">
```